# data is messed up when using boost::asio::async_write

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

when I was using boost::asio::async_write to send some large data, I found the data I received  was messed up, but total size was correct. it seemed like two groups of data overlapped. What can I do to avoid this happen?

Comment: You should provide a cut down working code sample exhibiting the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Without code, it's a stab in the dark..

1. Check that you are not using the same buffer for read/write operations
2. If you are using async_xxx operations, ensure that they are not overlapped, i.e. you must never call `async_read` until the previous read completes and same for `async_write`
3. You don't copy the data into the buffers correctly
4. You've got a network issue
5. Radiation from space is randomly modifying bits on the wire..

who knows...